# Eclipse & TestNg: How to exclude testng test-output folder

Tags: eclipse, testng

Currently, after doing a Maven build from inside eclipse, I am getting many warnings in the Problems-Tab related to html output produced by testng in the /test-output folder.
I was not able to find a way of excluding this folder from being validated.
Keep in mind that this folder is not in the build path obviously!

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Behzad

Comment: What are the warnings that you see?

Comment: Here is an example of the warnings created by created for html-reports generated by surefile-plugin:                               Description Resource Path Location Type
Attribute (name) is obsolete. Its use is discouraged in HTML5 documents. index.html /BookService2WebApp/target/surefire-reports line 156 HTML Problem

Comment: @niharika_neo, The real question is how to tell eclipse to exclude certain folders from being validated